# Can we setup a virtualized smart home in VMware for simulation purposes?

Tags: smart-home, networking

I want to assess an algorithm in an IoT network.

Can we use VMware to setup a network of devices like TV, fridge as well as laptops and then analyzing service discovery packets which are being exchanged between them?

Comment: This is far too broad to be an answerable question.  Generally speaking, you can simulate any system for which you can model the behavior you consider to matter.  It's not clear that vmware is going to be of particular help, unless you want to run the full operating systems of some of your system components in a virtualized environment, but it is unlikely that all of them will be platforms vmware supports, nor that vmware's networking will accurately model what might prove "interesting" about a real version of the network your propose.

Comment: I agree with Chris. I am also minded to vote to close - as the question stands. However, the title is intriguing enough for an upvote. I will wait & see if the question changes, before voting to close if it does not.  @soltan, please read [ask]. And welcome aboard, I am sure that you do have agood quesiton, if you can figure out how to ask it

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to virtualise? Each node will be running an embedded OS of some sort. QEMU might be a better fit, I think its possible to virtualise the network interfaces. Why do you want to virtualise rather than abstract these elements? What does vurtualisation give you over using a python script to generate trafic?

Comment: Maybe you can use [AWS instead.](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/iot/device-simulation-with-aws-iot-and-aws-lambda/)

Comment: This is a great question. Pity it was closed. Please post here if you ever find a solution. Might you get some help on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?